# SQL Server - Optimizing MAX() on large tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

My company has a series of SQL views. One critical view has a sub select that fetches the max(id) from a large table and joins with another table.

On a sample, I populated a test table with 1m rows. Max(id) (id is an integer value) takes 8 minutes. Top with and order by desc take 8 minutes. Just experimenting, I tried max(id) over(partion by(id)) takes one second. The result set is correct. Not sure why this sped things up so much. Any ideas much appreciated. New test table with 1m rows is tblmsg_nicholas

```
INNER JOIN LongviewHoldTable lvhold WITH (NOLOCK) ON lvhold.MsgID = case tm.MsgType                                         when 'LV_BLIM'                                      /*then (select max(tm2.ID) from [dbo].[TBLMSG_NICHOLAS] tm2
                                            where msgtype = 'LV_ALLOC' and TM.GroupID = tm2.groupID)*/
                                        /*then (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM TBLMSG_NICHOLAS TM2 WHERE msgtype = 'LV_ALLOC' and TM.GroupID =tm2.GroupID ORDER BY ID DESC)*/
                                        then (select max(tm2.ID) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) from [dbo].[TBLMSG_NICHOLAS] tm2
                                            where msgtype = 'LV_ALLOC' and TM.GroupID = tm2.groupID)
                                        else tm.ID
                                        end
WHERE
    TA.TARGETTASKID IS NOT NULL AND
    TA.RESPONSE IS NULL
```

Comment: Performance related questions need an execution plan - you can't investigate perform from the query alone. Also are you 100% aware of the implications of using `nolock`? Because you shouldn't normally use it.

Comment: If you want to get the MAX(Id) from a million rows and Id isn't sorted (e.g. part of an index), SQL Server has to read all million rows. If the table is wide, this can be, well, not good. MAX(id) OVER (PARTITION BY Id) doesn't really make sense to me - you want the highest Id for every unique value of Id - so it returned 1 million Ids in less than one second? Again, this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: You must be really desperate to use `WITH (NOLOCK)`. And you say that the query is running? This would mean that you are getting exactly one row with the subquery. But if so, why `MAX OVER`? Just use `MAX` instead.

Comment: how are the indexes on TBLMSG_NICHOLAS , and see in th equery plan what the subquery actually uses

Comment: Yes, the execution plan indicated no predicate and troubleshooting that further the max(id) is the culprit. Reading the documentation no predicate indicates a Cartesian product and that is totally unacceptable if working with any sizable table. Again, max() alone is terribly slow. Regarding NOLOCK, certainly something I can investigate as I inherited these queries. This is a trading system and locks and contention become a real issue. I agree that using the NOLOCK is problematic. The test table has a clustered index or at least constraint on ID. You got me...I chanced upon the partition over.

Comment: Perhaps move the logic to get the ID into 1 or 2 derived tables.  Then join the LongViewHoldTable to one of these to get the id required.

Comment: **Pro tip** Be scrupulous about formatting your SQL for readability. A year from now somebody (possibly yourself) will be happy you did. Reasoning about SQL is extremely important.

Answer (score 1):

About `MAX()`.  It looks like you are computing your `MAX()` more-or-less like this.

```sql
select max(tm2.ID)
  from [dbo].[TBLMSG_NICHOLAS] tm2
 where msgtype = 'LV_ALLOC' and TM.GroupID = tm2.groupID
```

An index on `TBLMSG_NICHOLAS (msgtype, GroupID, ID DESC)` accelerates that subquery. The query planner can random-access that index directly: the first matching row contains the `MAX(ID)` value you want.

But you also use a so-called dependent -- correlated -- subquery. It's usually a good idea to refactor such subqueries into JOINed independent subqueries. But it's hard to help you do that because you didn't show your entire query.